# The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance. Ao usar o date picker do kendo ui

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

Estou tentando armazenar no banco uma data através do componente [date picker do kendo ui](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/) ele envia para o meu banco nesse formato:

```
2019-07-23T00:00:00
```

Quando busco ele do banco e atribuir o valor do banco nele através do

> formcontrol.setValue()

eu recebo:

> Error: The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance. Check
>   http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/#toc-using-with-json
>   for possible resolution.

Esse é o valor que está vindo do meu banco: 2019-07-25T00:00:00

```
<kendo-datepicker [(value)]="ReferenciaMktDataDisponivel" formControlName="ReferenciaMktDataDisponivel"></kendo-datepicker>
```

Já tentei tirar o value e deixar apensa o formControlName mas não houve diferenças.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo visto essa biblioteca espera uma instancia do tipo Date, para isso vc tem que criar um objeto desse tipo parseando a data que vem do back

```
formcontrol.setValue(new Date())
```

ou

```
formcontrol.setValue(new Date(algumValor))
```

Comment: Eu envio para minha api POST: ReferenciaMktDataDisponivel: 2019-07-29T03:00:00.000Z Meu banco de dados salva com esse valor a coluna ReferenciaMktDataDisponivel: 2019-07-29 00:00:00.000


No meu ngOnInit eu verifico se possui data, caso possua, atributo o que tem no backend para os dados da tela:

ReferenciaMktDataDisponivel: new FormControl(new Date(dataItem.ReferenciaMktDataDisponivel))

Porém recebo:

The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date instance. Check http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/#toc-using-with-json

Comment: deu certo, o problema era o formulário filho que nao estava instanciando esse date...